# Dynamic s:form action

Tags: jsp, dynamic, struts2, action, ognl

Is there a way of specifying a dynamic `action` attribute in the `s:form` tag in Struts2? I want something like the below.

```
<c:set var="formAction" value="baseAction" />
<c:if test="${someCondition}">
     <c:set var="formAction" value="childAction" />Ac

<s:form method="post" action="${formAction}">
    <s:input....../>
    <s:select...../>
</s:form>
```

I know this can be achieved using javascript but I want to avoid refactoring.
I have tried achieving this using scriplets but the issue is that Struts2 tags doesn't take **runtime attributes**. I tried even with OGNL but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Struts2 tags to set values and check condition and then use OGNL to put `action` attribute.

```
<s:set var="formAction" value="'baseAction'" />
<s:if test="some_condition">
  <s:set var="formAction" value="'childAction'" />
</s:if>

<s:form method="post" action="%{#formAction}">
  <s:input....../>
  <s:select...../>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `s:url` tag to build the action url *dynamically*.

```
<s:url action="%{somePoperty}" var="myUrl"/>
<s:form action="%{#myUrl}">
```

In fact Struts tag's attributes don't accept not only scriptlets but also JSTL EL expressions.

Comment: There is no need to use `<s:url>` tag for `<s:form>` action.